# voiceConnection.receiver and voiceReciever.createPCMStream not receiving data

Tags: discord.js

The title is my problem. Here is the code I'm using:

```js
const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === args[0]);
if (!voiceChannel || voiceChannel.type !== 'voice') {
  return message.reply(`I couldn't find the voice channel ${args[0]}.`);
}

await voiceChannel.join();
let connection = message.guild.voiceConnection;
connection.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
    if(speaking) {
        const receiver = connection.createReceiver();
        const stream = receiver.createPCMStream(user);
        receiver.on('opus', (user, buffer) => {
            console.log('got some data');
        });
        stream.on('data', chunk => {
            console.log(chunk.length);
        });
    }
});
```

Nothing prints in the console, so I guess the stream and voice receiver just aren't receiving any data. Also, I've looked at lots of posts and lots of people use this code and it works for them. If anybody knows why this is happening please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late to answer but might help someone else.

You must send a silent frame first.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');
class Silence extends Readable {
  _read() {
    this.push(Buffer.from([0xF8, 0xFF, 0xFE]));
  }
}
```

Once the connection is established with the voice channel you can do something like this:

```
connection.on('ready', ()=>{
connection.play(new Silence(), { type: 'opus' });
})
```

For more details, you can visit this [page](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2929)